# How to show image fetched from mysqldatabase to imageview

Tags: android, android-volley, android-imageview

Here this is the layout in which I have to set the image of the user who successfully logged in[image]

and I have saved the url of the image in the table where all the details of the users are there....

So what I was trying is I am fetching the url of the image from the database and then tried to set it into imageview.. I have checked that the url is comming to the variable...

so as you can see in the above image it is not setting the image in imageview but when I assign the url first to the imgurl variable at the time of defining the variable then it works fine...

I don't know why this is happening... am I doing anything wrong or is there any other way to achieve this?

This is the code of the file...

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView usrname;
    ImageView profileimg;
    public static String imgurl = "";//here

    /**
     * Shared Preferences
     **/
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";

    /**
     * Shared Preferences
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        profileimg = findViewById(R.id.iv_display_image);
        usrname = findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
        /**Shared Preferences**/
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        /**Shared Preferences**/
        //fetching session data
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString(Name, "0");
        usrname.setText(name);
        fetchimg(name);
        LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(profileimg);
        Log.d("Oncreate img url", imgurl);
        loadImage.execute(imgurl);
    }

    private void fetchimg(String name) {

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://**url**//fetchimg.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.startsWith("Here")) {
                    String urlstr = getUrl(response, "Here ");
                    seturl(urlstr);
                    Log.d("urlstr value:", urlstr);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("vOLLEY ERROR", response.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("vOLLEY ERROR", error.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("login_name", "xxxxx");
                params.put("login_pass", "xxxxx");
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Dashboard.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void seturl(String urlstr) {
        this.imgurl = urlstr;
        Log.d("Image url set inside seturl", imgurl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboardmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void openeditprofile(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditProfileActivity.class));
    }

    private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView imageView;

        public LoadImage(ImageView profileimg) {
            this.imageView = profileimg;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String urlLink = strings[0];
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new java.net.URL(urlLink).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            profileimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    public static String getUrl(String string, String word) {

        // Check if the word is present in string
        // If found, remove it using removeAll()
        if (string.contains(word)) {

            // To cover the case
            // if the word is at the
            // beginning of the string
            // or anywhere in the middle
            String tempWord = word + " ";
            string = string.replaceAll(tempWord, "");

            // To cover the edge case
            // if the word is at the
            // end of the string
            tempWord = " " + word;
            string = string.replaceAll(tempWord, "");
        }

        // Return the resultant string
        return string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching image asynchronously, your `Asynctask` execute will be called with empty `imgUrl` as it not already fetched, move AsyncTask execution code in `onResponse` of fetching

```
private void fetchimg(String name) {

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://**url**//fetchimg.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.startsWith("Here")) {
                    String urlstr = getUrl(response, "Here ");
                    seturl(urlstr);
       

                   //here the url is ready to consume
                    Log.d("urlstr value:", urlstr);
                    //load the image now
                    LoadImage loadImage = new LoadImage(profileimg);
                    Log.d("Oncreate img url", imgurl);
                    loadImage.execute(imgurl);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("vOLLEY ERROR", response.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("vOLLEY ERROR", error.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("login_name", "xxxxx");
                params.put("login_pass", "xxxxx");
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Dashboard.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use **Glide** to display Image from Url into image view.

You have to add glide lib in app-level build.gradle file.

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

        Glide.with(this).load(url)
        .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(radius))
        .placeholder(R.drawable.drawable_image_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.drawable_image_placeholder)
        .into(ivProfile)

drawable_image_placeholder is the default imageview that displays
when getting the error to load the image. ivProfile is imageview .
```